# How to completely reset MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to be able to run MATLAB from a *perfectly clean slate*: no history, no snapshots, no customizations, ***nothing***.  Better yet, I'd like to be able to start a MATLAB session in the state that one would start at if one had *just* installed MATLAB.  Is this possible?

(Of course, I'm looking for a solution that does not require me to obliterate every trace of MATLAB from my hard disk [which probably cannot be done without reformatting the drive], and then re-install in it a fresh copy of MATLAB.)

FWIW, I'm running 7.11.0 R2010b.  (The shockingly rare/arcane solutions I've found online so far don't work with this version.)

Thanks!

Comment: Clearing out the `prefdir` folder will get rid of history etc, but it won't fix any modifications to built-in code that you may (but shouldn't) have done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best bet might be to open the prefdir and delete settings (untested by me):

*prefdir* - Folder containing preferences, history, and layout files

Syntax:

```
prefdir
folder = prefdir
folder = prefdir(1)
```

From here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/prefdir.html

Reset to a new instance (like you just opened a new session of MATLAB):

```
!matlab &
exit
```

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1093

Comment: You could probably even add a script to do this if you plan on doing it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual machine in Virtualbox, VirtualPC or similar.  Install OS + Matlab on it.  Snapshot or clone the system at that point.  Now, whenever you want to run a "fresh matlab", startup the VM from the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

One other approach is to use a newly-concocted directory as your `$HOME` for the session. Something like this (on Linux, using `bash` syntax)

```
$ mkdir /tmp/dummyHome
$ HOME=/tmp/dummyHome matlab &
```